# For parse migration, does mongodb have to be 3.2.6 or is 3.2.* ok?

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

Why is 3.0.* ok but 3.2 version has to specifically be 3.2.6? Is 3.2.1 ok?

Answer (score 1):

Any version is fine when doing a fresh install with `parse-server` but from parse.com you will not be able to move to 3.2. Seems that migration tool wont allow it.

I moved to 3.0 and from there did backup/restore to 3.2.

However i would always strongly suggest that one in general runs the latest version if you can.

I do know that all test on mongodb 3.2.6 are passing including geo queries.

Comment: Thanks for the help